# Finding x given y from an interpolating function

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation

I would like to put a dot on the point of a curve that has a specific y value but I don't know the x value.

A simple example of my code is

```
eqns = {y''[t] + y[t] == 3 a Sin[y[t]], y[0] == y'[0] == 1};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, y[1] + y[2], {t, 0, 5}, {a}];
Plot[pfun[a], {a, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

So say I want to find the x at which y=3. How? Once I have the two coordinates I know how to add the dot.
I guess I'm confused because the interpolating function gives you the y given the x, and I can't figure out how to do the inverse.
Also any suggestions of tutorials on how to use interpolating functions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: One comment: the subject should reflect the intent of the question. This one seems to have reversed `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 17):

One way is to use `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[pfun[x] == 3.0, {x, 0}]
```

Another way is `InverseFunction` which can be utilised like this

```
InverseFunction[pfun][3.0]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I tried the InverseFunction and it gave me InverseFunction[ParametricFunction[<>]][3]

Comment: @Lia, ah, that means `ParametricFunction[]` is not invertible. Stick with hal's first proposal, then.

Comment: @LiaChica The initial `x` in `FindRoot` is sometimes crucial to find the correct solution. Always remember that `FindRoot` is a local method with stepsize approximations etc where all kinds of bad things can happen. E.g. `FindRoot[Sin[x], {x, Pi/2}]` gives `-8.0*Pi` here. So you should have a good understanding of your function.

Comment: I managed to make FindRoot work once I gave it a specific domain to look in, e.g. FindRoot[pfun[x]==3.0,{x,0,5}] Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to use `InverseFunction` you could make interpolating function via `FunctionInterpolation`:

```
f = FunctionInterpolation[pfun[a], {a, -2, 2}];

InverseFunction[f][3]

(* 0.206407 *)
```