# Obtaining values from interpolating functions

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

A similar question has been asked in the post [HERE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/finding-y-given-x-from-an-interpolating-function) but the current question is more complicated: I have the following differential system

```
XX = x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]) (1 - Exp[-0.4 y[t]] - 0.2);
YY = y'[t] == 0.4 (-0.5 y[t]^0.2 + (1 - x[t])) ;

SOL = NDSolve[{XX, YY, x[0] == 18/100, y[0] == 40/100}, {x,y}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

The solution of this differential system yields the interpolating functions

```
{{x->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,100.`}},"<>"],y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,100.`}},"<>"]}}
```

I know that for some $y$'s there are multiple $x$'s because the dynamical relationship is non-linear, see the picture below

```
x[t_] = Evaluate[x[t] /. SOL[[1]]]
y[t_] = Evaluate[y[t] /. SOL[[1]]]
ParametricPlot[{y[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, time}, AxesLabel -> {"y(t)", "x(t)"}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

My question is: how can I extract, for a given level of $y$, the (potentially) multiple solutions of $x$ and the $t$ at which this occurs?

The importance is that the interpolation function is a function of two variables which are itself functions of time, and that I want to find all multiple solutions for $x$ for a given $y$. (The previous question  [HERE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/finding-y-given-x-from-an-interpolating-function) has only one argument in the interpolation function and it only yields unique solutions.)

Thank you sincerely for your help.

Comment: Without the full code that generated the interpolating function, can't say for sure.  But you could try  `NSolve` to get the `t` values and then plug them into the `x` function.

Comment: If it's an option, it might be easier to use `WhenEvent` to get the values you're looking for right in the  `NDSolve`.

Comment: You can use `WhenEvent[]` for this (if it's a one-time deal), or the `MeshFunctions` option of `Plot[]`/`ParametricPlot[]` in conjunction with `FindRoot[]`. There are a lot of previous threads on how to use these to find intersection points.

Comment: Part 1: A simple solution is to solve e.g. the interpolation function $y[t]$ for $t$ at a specific value of $y[t]$ via FindRoot (NSolve does not seem to work, it yields an InverseFunction solution and not an explicit solution). Finding the different roots can be done using [THIS](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range) or [THIS](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63663/find-all-roots-in-range)

Comment: Part 2: or [THIS](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444) approach. Then one can substitute the different $t$'s into the interpolating function for $x[t]$ and has the sets of solutions.