# Solve the interpolating function

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I would have asked how to obtain the x given the y in an interpolating function, and I found the answer from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/finding-y-given-x-from-an-interpolating-function). But another question raised.

I was dealing with measurement of the spectral characteristics, and I had a set of data, where x is the wavelength, y is the light intensity.And  I needed to find out the wavelength to which the half maximum light intensity corresponds. But the useful part of data was not enough.
In order to more accurately, I used `Interpolation` to get a `InterpolatingFunction`.

When I used `Solve` to obtain the half maximum intensity corresponding to wavelength, it failed and told me:

```
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
```

My codes including data are simple and as follows:

```
data = {{646.38`, 2991}, {646.46`, 3085}, {646.53`, 3204}, {646.6`, 
3227}, {646.68`, 3183}, {646.75`, 3121}, {646.83`, 3176}, {646.9`,
 3354}, {646.97`, 3475}, {647.05`, 3645}, {647.12`, 
3798}, {647.2`, 4146}, {647.27`, 4321}, {647.34`, 5067}, {647.42`,
 5684}, {647.49`, 6135}, {647.57`, 7189}, {647.64`, 
8342}, {647.71`, 9449}, {647.79`, 10788}, {647.86`, 
12591}, {647.94`, 15210}, {648.01`, 19037}, {648.08`, 
22940}, {648.16`, 26676}, {648.23`, 31403}, {648.31`, 
36365}, {648.38`, 41122}, {648.45`, 45664}, {648.53`, 
50078}, {648.6`, 49445}, {648.68`, 45498}, {648.75`, 
37491}, {648.82`, 29894}, {648.9`, 22635}, {648.97`, 
15810}, {649.05`, 10029}, {649.12`, 6141}, {649.19`, 
5913}, {649.27`, 5649}, {649.34`, 4057}, {649.42`, 
3734}, {649.49`, 3810}, {649.56`, 3880}, {649.64`, 
2938}, {649.71`, 3284}, {649.79`, 3349}, {649.86`, 
3109}, {649.93`, 3134}};
fun = Interpolation[data];
Solve[fun[x] == 50078/2, x]
```

where the maximum intensity is from data

From the document of Mathematica, I know that the algorithm of `Interpolation` is fitting polynomial curves between successive data points, and `Solve` is mainly used in linear and polynomial equations.

The question is why can't `Solve` solve the equation including `InterpolatingFunction`

Comment: I would use `FindRoot`, although that doesn't answer your last question.

Comment: Don't know why you cannot use `Solve`, but if you use `FindRoot[fun[x] == 50078/2, {x, 649}]` you get the answer.

Comment: But anyway, `InterpolatingFunction` isn't a polynomial but rather a sequence of pasted together polynomials, making it impossible for `Solve` to use nicely.

Comment: Actually i don't understand the difference between the meanings of "a polynomial" and "a sequence of pasted together polynomials"

Comment: What @march is referring to is conventionally called [piecewise polynomial interpolation](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=piecewise+polynomial+interpolation&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) -- see also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59963

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of my solution to [Extracting the function from InterpolatingFunction object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59944/extracting-the-function-from-interpolatingfunction-object/59963#59963),
which converts an `InterpolatingFunction` to a `Piecewise` polynomial interpolation.

```
pwf = Piecewise[
     Map[{InterpolatingPolynomial[#1, x], x < #[[3, 1]]} &, Most[#]], 
     InterpolatingPolynomial[Last@#1, x]] &@Partition[data, 4, 1];

{x1, x2} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];

sol = Solve[pwf == 50078/2 && x1 <= x <= x2, x]
(*  {{x -> 648.126}, {x -> 648.873}}  *)
```

`NSolve` works too.